# The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'sheet1$'

Tags: excel, vb6

So, I was creating  a simple application in vb6. It is to display the Excel sheet1 contents into Data grid view.

```
  If CommonDialog1.FileName = "" Then
    Label2.Caption = "No file selected."
  Else
    file_name = CommonDialog1.FileName
    Label2.Caption = file_name
  End If

  Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
  Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

  cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= file_name;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"
  If cn.State = adStateOpen Then
          MsgBox "Connected to Excel File"
  End If

  strQuery = "SELECT * FROM `Sheet1$`"   <<Error Highlighted>>

  Set rs = cn.Execute(strQuery)


  rs.Close
  cn.Close
```

But I receive this error:

> Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object
>   'sheet1$'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and
>   the path name correctly.

Comment: Try `"SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"`

Comment: I have tried it. Same Error!

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uYzmX.png

Answer (score 1):

```
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= file_name;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"
```

Here the filename is literally "file_name" - you need to concatenate the variable into the connection string:

```
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
          file_name & ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"
```